# How do I set up a Rails application with Semantic UI?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, asset-pipeline, semantic-ui

I have installed the semantic UI rails gem

```
gem 'semantic-ui-rails'
```

I am now attempting to create a simple navigation bar with the following sample code from Symantec UI documentation:

```
<div class="ui secondary pointing menu">
  <a class="active item">
    Home
  </a>
  <a class="item">
    Messages
  </a>
  <a class="item">
    Friends
  </a>
  <div class="right menu">
    <a class="ui item">
      Logout
    </a>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="ui segment">
  <p></p>
</div>
```

The plain text appears but without the semantic UI formatting and styling.  do I need to configure something in order to get semantic UI up and running?

Comment: Does my answer works for you?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Place the following line in your Gemfile:

```
gem 'semantic-ui-sass', github: 'doabit/semantic-ui-sass'
```

Run the bundler:

```
bundle install
```

Import semantic-ui on your application.css.scss:

```
@import "semantic-ui";
```

Require the javascript on your application.js:

```
//= require semantic-ui
```

After that you should be able to use to components of semantic-ui
You can find more info in the [gem repo](https://github.com/doabit/semantic-ui-sass)

Comment: This gem doesn't allow you to change your theme.

Comment: Can you have semantics-ui with bootstrap? Or working with both create conflicts?

Comment: I think you can add the semantic-ui css and js that you like to your bootstrap based project, but I think you would have to do that manually.